# Parallax with SVG groups

Tags: css, svg, parallax

I created an svg graphic using flash for my personal website. The SVG has multiple elements in which the html code provided is grouped within the SVG tag. I'm trying to apply a parallax to each group but can't seem to get it to work.

I've tried exporting each layer as separate SVGs through Illustrator, however, when applying it in code the SVGs are not proportionate or even at their x,y coordinates.

A sample of the code of the full SVG can be accessed through this link
http://codepen.io/Aricha03/pen/YWwaWB

Here is the code I'm currently working on

```
</svg>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <h1>THIS IS A SAMPLE HEADER</h1>
        <p>LOREM IPSUM TIME!</p>
        <p>sldafksdlfasdfjasldkfajsldkfajsdlfsssss</p>
        <div style="background-color: green; height: 1000px; width: 100px"></div>
    </div>
```

As for the CSS

```
    .parallax {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
  }
  .parallax_1 {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
  }
  .parallax_2 {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-1px);
    transform: translateZ(-1px);
  }
  .parallax_3 {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-2px);
    transform: translateZ(-2px);
  }  
.parallax_4 {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-3px);
    transform: translateZ(-3px);
  }
.parallax_5 {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-4px);
    transform: translateZ(-4px);
  }
.parallax_6{
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-5px);
    transform: translateZ(-5px);
  }
.parallax_7{
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-6px);
    transform: translateZ(-6px);
  }
```

Comment: For the individual layer SVGs to scale and position correctly, you need to make sure that they all have the same `viewBox` value.  Ie. likely the same as the original SVG (`"960 -650 3840 2380"`).

Comment: Nope, that didn't work at all. However, changing the width of the div to pixels instead of percentage did expand it, so I might make a function to control that with the max-width css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SVG` is a two-dimensional graphics.
In 1.1/2 version there is no z-axis can control.

The interface of this function:

https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#InterfaceSVGTransform

> void setTranslate(in float tx, in float ty) raises(DOMException);

Seems you can't even control it by css.

You need to use `d3.js` or `svg.js` to manipulate it. Or just wrap each components(cloud, mountains...) in html tags and control it by css.

Comment: So would I be able to modify the z-axis using a newer svg version? Or do you know of a solution via JavaScript? I've tried searching online but to no avail did I find an answer.

Comment: @Aricha You need to use `d3js` or `svgjs` to manipulate it. or wrap each components(cloud, mountain.. ) separately by the `svg` or other HTML tag so you can simply control the z-axis.

Comment: Appreciate the help dude. I was able to move the SVGs with a javascript translate call using D3 to help me out, however I can't get a proper z-axis positioning to go. I'll use images for now and come back to that later :)